# AppHarbor - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, google-api, appharbor

Running into a strange problem with my MVC solution hosted on AppHarbor. Locally it runs perfectly fine, but i'm getting an exception thrown to me when on production (appharbor).

Code from stack trace:

```
string keyFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/key.p12");
string serviceAccountEmail = "my-email-here@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
   {
      Scopes = new[] { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/" }
   }.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Further jumping into this problem, the problem is from the first line of my code:

```
string keyFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/key.p12");
```

After examining the build, it seems that my key.p12 isn't even on the server (even after pushing it up). Does AppHarbor reject certain files?

Answer (score 0):

AppHarbor doesn't reject certain files, but MsBuild is configured to use an explicit output directory. This likely differs from your local environment where the solution is usually built in the same directory. By default, the MsBuild targets used by AppHarbor will not copy certain files unless you explicitly configure it.

The issue can be fixed by referencing the certificate file in your project and then setting the "Build Action" property to "Content". That should cause the file to be copied to the output directory.

Another solution would be to embed the certificate as an embedded resource and here's [initializing an embedded certificate and installing it in the user's certificate store](https://gist.github.com/runesoerensen/4546909). Note that you usually don't have to install the certificate to use it.